# Concept of the working of friction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I have been trying to solve the exercises of HC Verma- Concepts of Physics. Can't understand the solution of one of the questions on friction.

**Question**

The friction coefficient between an a pair of shoes and the ground is 0.90. Suppose a superman wears these shoes and races for 50m. There is no upper limit on his capacity of running at high speeds.speeds. Find the minimum time he will have to take in completing the 50m starting from rest.

This is the solution I found from the web.

**Answer**
[image: Solution Image from web.]

So my question is, why is $ ma-\mu mg =0?$

If $ ma $ is balanced by the force of friction, why is the man accelerating at all?

Could you clear this up for me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why shouldn't he be accelerating? $ma$ and $\mu m g$ are *not* oppsite forces acting upon the *same* object.

Comment: If $ma$ and $\mu m g$ are not acting on the same object, how can an equation be made from them? Sorry, excuse me if my question is just stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation of a misconception that happens over and over again. The force that the ground can exert on the (super)man is equal and opposite to the force of friction of the man on the ground. It is precisely *because* the man is accelerating that the force of friction is even experienced. The force of the ground on his shoes is the force that accelerates his mass.

There are many similar questions on this site.

Comment: So, cannot $ma-\mu mg >0?$

Comment: No it can't - trying to do so your feet would slip.

Comment: How would you run on ice? "The force of the ground on his shoes is the force that accelerates his mass."

Comment: @user31748 it is very hard to _accelerate_ on ice.